# Corporate nation with stocks and owners

Tags: society, government, technological-development, currency, internet

Knowing that the dollar has its value derived from the country's GDP and the country is supported by taxes and a fixed structure of 3 powers. So Why not write a computer program to do this? OK, so we can create a currency called Cryptodollar, the structure of 3 powers can be fixed into the blockchain, and the tax can come from the creation of max 1% of coins per month, put into a fund, used for conquering territory. OK, now all we need is make a independent group use the coins and decide with their votes (vote=coin) how the tax fund is used to conquer (obviously want to maintain their coins value, so mismanaging the fund equal to self-boycott). Eventually it would dominate everything, since it would be a lot more limited, efficient and free market than current governments.

I mean, it can be done, right guys?

Edit: I'm talking about creating a cryptocurrency in real life that is like a stock in a corporation, you get value AND vote. You can buy the vote if you buy the coin. But instead of a corporation you get a corporate nation, which you control the already conquered territory, and vote to conquer more territory.

The 1% a month is equal to 12% GDP of the year, so it's not 30%, but it's not little.

The nation is better than the usual state for two reasons: It's limited and efficient. You can change anything digitally, by direct vote of the owners, and the owners have interest in managing the tax fund in the best way possible, contrary to today's government, where if the politicians mismanage the government money there's no punishment in most cases.

It's like a dictatorship, but it can have lots of owners and each one can get out any time they want, and people can become owners any time they want.

What I said about the independent group. The thing is, the best way to implement this idea if there's some already established group of people that live in lands that governments don't own, and apply the blockchain I described in their lives. That way the land is tied to the blockchain, since the owners won't be able to agree simultaneously to stop using the system, the ones who stay will ban the people who tried to boycott the system. But you can try to apply the blockchain first, and then invade some land, but that's more complicated the way I see.

Mithrandir24601 I'm talking about the real world, I didn't create a world, the difference from the  is that the land is tied to the blockchain, and contrary to common governments of today, which can do anything with unlimited force, the blockchain will always go against rebellion individuals, because it has a fixed structure of power, and once the nation use it, they wont be able to get out.

Comment: you do realize developed nations go through 30-50% of GDP at government funds (AKA taxes) 1% would not even get you paved roads.

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not really sure what you're actually asking here - are you asking for the feasibility of actually doing something in the real world [note: this would be off-topic], or are you looking at building a world with this, in which case could you be more specific about what your problem is and what makes this created world different to the real one? Thanks

Comment: You want to replace the government with a cryptocurrency with the main goal to conquer territory? That doesn't make much sense, unless you want to create a totalitarian regime controlled by a computer? If that is the case you should make the question clearer about that. You also want an independent group to make the decisions about war. Lastly, the last statement is wrong: dictature doesn't always mean free market, it's not even related. Your system is just a dictature with a different currency.

Comment: Kind of. I would describe it more as a corporate nation, because it has many owners, and the owners can change at any time. But yeah, it would have complete control of the territory, but all the owners/dictators would have to agree to change something. People are free to not visit or enter the nation, but the owners would have an incentive to avoid being a dictatorship in the tradicional sense, since they would want people to enter the nation and work there.

Answer (score 3):

The American greenback already fits the bill. It is no longer controlled by America, Over 50% of them are outside of the US soil,and will never see it.  The major trading nations - China and Europe - have a vested interest in maintaining a constant Greenback value, since any fluctuation hurts them more than the US. Taxes have little to do with the value of an international currency. It's all about its usefulness and stability in trading. You want to KNOW that the value today when you buy a product will be the same value a month from now when you sell the product.